# Regex replace in notepad++ but only certain parts of line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with lines like this:

```
<a href="/foldername/Subfolder/anothersubfolder/Name%20of%20Document.pdf">Name%20of%20Document.pdf</a>
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
<a href="/foldername/Subfolder/anothersubfolder/Name%20of%20Document.pdf">Name of Document.pdf</a>
```

ie, I would like to replace the escaped space characters (%20) with a literal space character, but only in the link name, not in the url.

I will also need to remove other escaped characters, not only spaces.

How can I do this in notepad++?

Comment: This is not a code or regex writing service. What effort have you made to try to do this yourself? Hints: First write a regex that isolates the part after the first `>` and before the next `<` into a capturing group, and then work with that capture group content by replacing `%` + the two digits after it with a space.

Comment: Is there only one href per line? Is there anything else on a line?

Comment: @KenWhite Get over yourself... I know quite well what this site is - it's for asking questions you don't know the answer to. Perhaps you could see if there's a social interaction stackexchange site that can help you. It's so magnanimous of you to give me a hint but I still would appreciate an answer to the question. I know how to use brackets and `\1` to do a backreference but not how to do multiple replacements inside the backreference when replacing in notepad++. I googled like crazy before asking the question, I pray I put in enough effort to satisfy you.

Comment: @Toto There's only one href per line in the file.

Comment: There's nothing to get over. Your question shows zero effort that you made. If you made efforts to solve it yourself, you should include that information in your post, because if you don't we have no idea that you've done so. I'd suggest you spend some time thinking about what a poor idea it is to be rude and insulting to people you're asking for **free help** to solve **your problems**. I see no evidence (based on anything you've included in your question's content) that you've done even a single search, written a single regex attempt, or done anything but beg for someone here to write it.

Comment: Maybe https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ can help you, but don't expect miracles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have only one href per line, you could do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?>[^%\n\r]*\K%20`
- Replace with: `A SPACE`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Click <kbd>Replace all</kbd> as many times as needed**

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
.+?         : 1 or more any character, not greedy
>           : literally >
[^%\r\n]*   : 0 or more character that is not % or line break
\K          : Forget all we have seen until this point
%20         : literally %20
```

- DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but it doesn't work properly for me. It works for the first few `Replace all` but after that, removes the %20's from the href every second line, like it's ignoring the newlines. I don't have `. matches newline` checked. How would I get it to respect the newlines and not go past? It looks to me like the `[^%\r\n]*` part should do that already.

Comment: @localhost: Strange, it works pretty fine for me. Could you edit your question and add an extract of the file you're working on. Add, I haven't the same regex in explanation. This the one in explanation you have to use. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: @localhost: What version of Npp are you using. Here I have 7.4.2

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. I was just using a file with 4 lines identical to the line in my question. The real files I was working on are at work, and I've actually finished the job but wanted to know how to do this as a learning exercise. I updated Npp to 7.4.2 when your first regex didn't work for me before, but I was using 6.something before that.

Comment: BTW you must have `Wrap around` ticked, or it doesn't do the first line.

Comment: @localhost: True, I allways keep it checked.